# jqrid column width should be displayed based on the length of the column content

Tags: jqgrid

in my jqgrid i have several columns, the first columns length is big, the remaining columns are small. So all the columns are having a big width. I want the column width to be displayed as per the data content of the column. I cannot specify the width in pixels.
I tried using the autowidth propety but it doesnt work for me. Any suggestions please.